# XStream empty tag when List is empty

Tags: java, xstream

When using XStream, I get am empty tag(on the collection field) if I try to serialise an Object has `java.util.List` collection which is empty. How to I remove that empty tag in the xml output?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your List variable must be **null** and not containing an empty list to avoid the 'empty' tag.

```
List list = getList();
if(list.isEmpty()) { list = null; }

// Serialization ...
```

**EDIT:**

If you want that to be done automatically you need to create a custom converter, follow this tutorial:
http://x-stream.github.io/converter-tutorial.html

Comment: where should I set the list to null?

Comment: you must set your list to null (if empty) before serializing. but please provide code if you want a more helpful answer.

Comment: Sure! That would work.But, it gets messy if I have a parent-child relationship and parent has a list of children, and the children also maintain a list of other children for example. Does it imply that I have to check every list defined to ensure it's null if it's empty? Isn't there an effective way, because this can work in a simple object graph, but once this increases, it can get to be ineffective.

Comment: No you need to create a custom converter, it's way smarter. I edited answer with link to tutorial.